# Pentaho: How to export csv to SharePoint / OneDrive

Tags: excel, sharepoint, pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I have a transformation that has `Table input` to get the data from the Oracle server.

In order to export the data/table in Excel (xlsx) or CSV **to the shared network drive**, we all know to use `Microsoft Excel writer` or `Text file output`.

Que:
How to export the xlsx or csv files to **Sharepoint**?

**What I tried so far (2 methods)**

**1:**
I have got the link for my Sharepoint folder and tried connecting it using `SFTP` as below.

[image: Pentaho SFTP]

[image: Pentaho SFTP Edit]

However, I get this error message.

[image: Error]

**2:**

Used `HTTP Client` as below and surprisingly it runs successfully.
[image: HTTPS Success]
[image: HTTP Client Edit]
However, the file does not exist when checked in that folder in SharePoint. When I entered some random characters in the server name, it still runs successfully. So, I'm not sure where the file is being sent to by Pentaho.

Does anyone know how to upload the data file to SharePoint via Pentaho?